# CheckBox Control in Visual studio asp.net 2005 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

May you please help me on this: I developed a web application that has Checkboxes and i want to show some controls when the user tick the box and hide them when the user untick the box. I only managed to do the showing part when the user tick the box, now i'm failing to hide them when the user untick the box.

Here is the showing part of the my code:

```
 protected void chkboxMentor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMentorName.Visible = true;
        txtMentorName.Visible = true;
        lblMentorStuff.Visible = true;
        txtMentorStaffNo.Visible = true;
        lblMentorDate.Visible = true;
        btnShowCal.Visible = true;
    }
```

Please help me with the hiding part.

Any help please!!! It will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Visible` property to the checkbox's `Checked` property.

Comment: Guys, your answers are all relevant. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
        lblMentorName.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
        txtMentorName.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
        lblMentorStuff.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
        txtMentorStaffNo.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
        lblMentorDate.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
        btnShowCal.Visible = chkBoxMentor.Checked;
```

EDIT: More elegant solution would be to put these controls in a `Panel` and just set the `Visible` property of that using the checkbox's `Checked` property

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, the OP wanted visibility toggled based on check box status not the label visibility

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks says

just set

```
<Yourontrolname>.Visible = chkboxMentor.checked
```

for each control you wish to toggle

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void chkboxMentor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     if(chkboxMentor.Checked)
    {
        lblMentorName.Visible = true;
        txtMentorName.Visible = true; 
        lblMentorStuff.Visible = true;
        txtMentorStaffNo.Visible = true;
        lblMentorDate.Visible = true;
        btnShowCal.Visible = true; 
    }
    else
    {

        lblMentorName.Visible = false;
        txtMentorName.Visible = false; 
        lblMentorStuff.Visible = false;
        txtMentorStaffNo.Visible = false;
        lblMentorDate.Visible = false;
        btnShowCal.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```